# How to build JSON object with nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am constructing a JSON object with nested objects in Javascript.  Is there an easy way to do this in Javascript without using eval()?

```
var data_json = "data = {'"+field_name+"':{'answers':{";
for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++){
    data_json += "'" + i + "':" + "'" + answers[i] + "',";
}
data_json = data_json.replace(/,$/,"");
data_json = data_json + "}}}";

eval(data_json);
```

Result:

```
data={'myfield':{'answers':{'0':'The answer', '1':'Another answer'}}};
```

Comment: why are you constructing json in javascript, javascript IS json

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  JSON is "JavaScript Object Notation".  It is a language-independent data interchange format.

Comment: Correct i should have expanded on what i was saying.  JavaScript objects are json, there's no need to use string concat just build the object graph as is done in the selected answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a, data = {};
data[field_name] = { "answers" : { } };
a = data[field_name]["answers"];

for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++){
   a[i] = answers[i];
}


console.log(data);
```

As a side note, if `data[field_name]["answers"]` contains numeric keys only, it should be an array and not an object, so `data[field_name]` should be `= { "answers" : [ ]};`

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd use JSON.stringify to convert your javascript objects into a json string format.

Check these out for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.85).aspx

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

You can also use
JSON.parse to go the other way (from string to object)

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);
```

http://www.json.org/js.html